# Videos with Lubuntu and Libreoffice

Tags: video, lubuntu, libreoffice

I have a presentation with a video in it (.ogg). While it works really well on my regular desktop (Unity), on my 4-years old laptop with Lubuntu installed LibreOffice cannot play the video, it just stays white. However, I can still play the file in GNOME MPlayer.

Any idea on the codec I need to install or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that openjdk doesn't support the JMF, which is required in order to play videos. This following script from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) installs sun's java and fixes the problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this may not be answer ,I do not see the comment option.
 I want to ask you have you tried VLC media Player
VLC can play almost all Formats for you even if you have a slow pc.

Type this in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: New users often cannot comment on questions, that's normal. I have vlc installed though, but it doesn't make a difference, because I can already play it in GNOME MPlayer, so the support is already there.

Comment: You said it cannot play the video and then you are saying every thing works. 
Is the problem already solved?

Comment: I can play, libreoffice can't

Comment: have you tried Openoffice?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently after switching to Xubuntu 13.04. I could embed video but the frame appeared with "sound icon" (instead of question mark which appears on embedded videos) and gray frame appeared in presentation mode. Installing Oracle JRE did not help.

I am not sure what exactly helped in my case though I am quite sure the problem was GStreamer-related, probably due to some old configuration in my home directory.

Try removing `~/.gstreamer-0.10` directory (if it is present).

Or try installing `gstreamer-0.10-gconf` or `gconf-defaults-service` – I doubt this actually helped problem, but there may be some obsolete settings which get fixed this way.